# htaccess rewrite rule, match URL params

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I am sorry to ask a so trivial question, but I cannot find answers in RewriteRule docs. It should be something very simple that I am missing here...

I need to redirect

```
/index.php/component/users/?view=login
```

to

```
/index.php
```

if the URL matches "view=login"

I tried

```
RewriteRule ^((.*)\?view=login(.*))$ /index.php? [R,L]
```

and it doesn't work though testing it on www.regextester.com or www.regexpal.com shows a match

At the same time matching the substring "users" works perfectly fine using

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/users(.*)$ /index.php? [R,L]
```

What is the problem with my regex matching "view-login"? Why does it work on a tester and doesn't on a live site?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
I have managed to get it work using RewriteCond and RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} login
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /? [R,L]
```

Still I cannot understand why a single RewriteRule doesn't work to match string after "?". It works only for the part of the string before "?".

I would appreciate if someone could explain that. Thanks!

Comment: `RewriteRule ^((.*)\?view=login(.*))$ /index.php? [R,L]` it should be `RewriteRule ^((.*)\/?view=login(.*))$ /index.php? [R,L]`

Comment: Why it matches on tester as you're having `\?` as optional so `(.*)` will match upto `/index.php/component/users/?`

Comment: Thanks guys. The suggested RewriteRule ^((.*)\/?view=login(.*))$ /index.php? [R,L] doesn't work also. String match works only for substrings before "?". It looks as only the part of the string up to "?" is being analyzed. Any suggestions?